# ImGui Button Icon not alignment properly

Tags: game-engine, imgui

[image]

My icon is not working properly in the `ImGui::Button`. I'm using the custom font named material-design from [IconFontCppHeaders](https://github.com/juliettef/IconFontCppHeaders). My other icons are perform nicely, but the grid one is not acting correct. Here is my code:

```
ImGui::Button(_transparency ? ICON_MD_GRID_ON "##enable###gridTransparency" : ICON_MD_GRID_OFF "##disable###gridTransparency")
```

This line is used to change the icon just in one button, and it works fine. Is there any flags in ImGui that can adjust icons in Button?

Comment: more than likely, it depends on how the icon font was created. IcoMoon (for example) likes to align the bottom of the icon to the text baseline, which generally means it is placed a little too high.

Answer (score 0):

When Loading the offending icon font, set FontConfig.GlyphOffset.y an amount appropriate for the font size. This will shift the icons down a few pixels and align them appropriately.

You will need to experiment with specific values or ratios